# Как корректно соединить имя файла с путем к файлу?

Tags: c#

Как корректно соединить имя файла с путем к файлу?

Comment: По моему это оно http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/CSharp/System.IO/Path/C_Path_Combine_String_.htm

Comment: string path = @"C:\temp\file.txt"; ты про это говоришь?

Comment: А за что минусы? Хороший простой вопрос, не?

Comment: Ответы хорошие, особенно с обработкой исключения. Взял на заметку.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Используйте метод `Path.Combine` (пространство имён `System.IO`). Пример:

```
string fullPath = Path.Combine(@"C:\Log", "log.txt");
```

Answer (score 3):

Если вам нужно, чтобы в случае "неправильных" имен генерировалось исключение:

```
    if (Path.GetFileName(fileName) != fileName)
    {
        throw new Exception("'fileName' is invalid!");
    }

    string combined = Path.Combine(dir, fileName);
```

Если просто нужно смерджить не заморачиваясь:

```
    string combined = Path.Combine(dir, Path.GetFileName(fileName));
```